# Helping with LP timeseries using PuLP

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, linear-programming, pulp

I am currently working on an timeseries LP optimization problem using the PuLP library in Python, and I have encountered some issues. Below is a detailed breakdown of my code

```
    import pandas as pd
from pulp import LpMaximize, LpProblem, LpVariable, lpSum, value

hourly_prices_df = pd.read_csv("new_datav2v1.csv")
hourly_prices = hourly_prices_df["price"].tolist()


hours = len(hourly_prices)

print(hours)

# Decision variables
P_nominal = 24  #power nominal
C_nominal = 24 #capacity nominal
h_rt = 0.85     #efficiency  


Pd = LpVariable.dicts("Pd", range(1, hours + 1), lowBound=0, upBound=P_nominal)
Pc = LpVariable.dicts("Pc", range(1, hours + 1), lowBound=0, upBound=P_nominal)
C = LpVariable("C", lowBound=0, upBound=C_nominal)

lp_problem = LpProblem("Energy_Optimization", LpMaximize)

#objective function
lp_problem += lpSum((Pd[i] * hourly_prices[i - 1] - Pc[i] * hourly_prices[i - 1]) for i in range(1, hours + 1)), "Objective"

for i in range(1, hours + 1):
    lp_problem += 0 <= (Pc[i] - (1/h_rt) * Pc[i]) <= C_nominal, f"Charge_Constraint_Hour_{i}"

for i in range(2, hours + 1):
    lp_problem += Pc[i] == Pc[i-1] + Pd[i-1], f"Hour_{i}_Cyclic_Behavior_Constraint"
lp_problem += Pc[1] == Pc[hours] + Pd[hours], "Hour_1_Cyclic_Behavior_Constraint"


for i in range(1, hours + 1):
    lp_problem += 0 <= Pd[i] <= P_nominal
    lp_problem += 0 <= Pc[i] <= P_nominal


lp_problem += sum(Pd[i] for i in range(1, hours + 1)) == 2 * C_nominal


lp_problem.solve()


print("Optimization Status:", lp_problem.status)
print("Optimal Revenue (Rday):", lp_problem.objective.value())

charged_hours = [i for i in range(1, hours + 1) if Pc[i].value() > 0]
discharged_hours = [i for i in range(1, hours + 1) if Pd[i].value() > 0]

print("Charged Hours:", charged_hours)
print("Discharged Hours:", discharged_hours)

for i in range(1, hours + 1):
    print(f"Hour {i}: Charge = {Pc[i].value()}, Discharge = {Pd[i].value()}")
```

And the results which has a status of - 1 and of course the charge and discharge is not right.

```
Optimization Status: -1
Optimal Revenue (Rday): 2880.0
Charged Hours: []
Discharged Hours: [24]
Hour 1: Charge = 0.0, Discharge = 0.0
Hour 2: Charge = 0.0, Discharge = 0.0
Hour 3: Charge = 0.0, Discharge = 0.0
Hour 4: Charge = 0.0, Discharge = 0.0
Hour 5: Charge = 0.0, Discharge = 0.0
Hour 6: Charge = 0.0, Discharge = 0.0
Hour 7: Charge = 0.0, Discharge = 0.0
Hour 8: Charge = 0.0, Discharge = 0.0
Hour 9: Charge = 0.0, Discharge = 0.0
Hour 10: Charge = 0.0, Discharge = 0.0
Hour 11: Charge = 0.0, Discharge = 0.0
Hour 12: Charge = 0.0, Discharge = 0.0
Hour 13: Charge = 0.0, Discharge = 0.0
Hour 14: Charge = 0.0, Discharge = 0.0
Hour 15: Charge = 0.0, Discharge = 0.0
Hour 16: Charge = 0.0, Discharge = 0.0
Hour 17: Charge = 0.0, Discharge = 0.0
Hour 18: Charge = 0.0, Discharge = 0.0
Hour 19: Charge = 0.0, Discharge = 0.0
Hour 20: Charge = 0.0, Discharge = 0.0
Hour 21: Charge = 0.0, Discharge = 0.0
Hour 22: Charge = 0.0, Discharge = 0.0
Hour 23: Charge = 0.0, Discharge = 0.0
Hour 24: Charge = 0.0, Discharge = 48.0
```

The data I use in the csv

```
    time,price
2023-11-30 00:00:00,104.79
2023-11-30 01:00:00,104.52
2023-11-30 02:00:00,102.2
2023-11-30 03:00:00,100.01
2023-11-30 04:00:00,101.63
2023-11-30 05:00:00,106.3
2023-11-30 06:00:00,129.41
2023-11-30 07:00:00,156.07
2023-11-30 08:00:00,76.49
2023-11-30 09:00:00,95.01
2023-11-30 10:00:00,60.0
2023-11-30 11:00:00,67.13
2023-11-30 12:00:00,75.01
2023-11-30 13:00:00,105.68
2023-11-30 14:00:00,111.59
2023-11-30 15:00:00,195.0
2023-11-30 16:00:00,226.0
2023-11-30 17:00:00,253.76
2023-11-30 18:00:00,187.24
2023-11-30 19:00:00,153.94
2023-11-30 20:00:00,122.01
2023-11-30 21:00:00,122.0
2023-11-30 22:00:00,87.0
2023-11-30 23:00:00,60.0
```

I tried a few different approaches but I don't seem to figure it out

The breakdown of my needed parameters

[image: My needed obj function etc]

The problems I think I need help:

1. Objective Function: I would appreciate any insights
   into the objective function to ensure it aligns with the goal of
   maximizing revenue.
2. Charge Level Constraints: The charge level constraints might not be
   correctly formulated. I used (Pc[i] - (1/h_rt) * Pc[i]) to represent
   the charge level for each hour. Should this be modified?
3. Cyclic Behavior Constraints: While attempting to ensure cyclic
   behavior, I encountered issues, and the constraints might not be
   correctly formulated.
4. General Code Review: Any suggestions for improving the overall code
   structure, logic, or efficiency would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where did you get "the math" (image) for this?  It doesn't appear to be correct.  There is no use of `C` in the formulation, which is required to not bust max state of charge.  Related:  The Charge Level Constraint is nonsensically wrong.

Comment: I made the image my self using data from 3 scientific journals

Comment: OK.  Let's back up to that....  Your formulation isn't correct.  In most LP's, there are constraints that are "for each" type and you don't have that type of nomenclature.  You should for state of charge.  It needs to be within bounds "for each" timestep.  And you will need to include `C` to do that.  I recommend starting with a *simpler* model that just does a sequence of periods (no cyclic stuff) and get that working, then branch out from there.

Comment: Yes I understand what you are saying